# How to update state in angular 2 redux?

Tags: angular, redux

I use [ng2-redux](https://github.com/angular-redux/ng2-redux) and [angular2-hmr](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-hmr) module. I'm trying to update ng2-redux state if developer changes any file in the project.

If developer changes any file, then hmrOnDestroy is called. I save current state in this method ( `let state = this.redux.getState()` ). `this.redux` is an instance of `NgRedux`. Then hmrOnInit is called, I should update current state in this method. How to do it? There is no method this.redux.setState()